# NullReferenceException in SharePoint 2010 page layout after restore

Tags: 2010, error, restore

It is SharePoint 2010 publishing website. I have a page layout with some user controls added to it. These users controls have rad editor controls in them. Everything was working perfectly unless one day I restored a backup from production to my dev and test environments. This page on dev and test environments started to give "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". When I debug the controls are actually null, and debugger comes directly to set function for the fields, it does not call page_load function before coming to setter.

These same controls are working in other page layouts even after backup restore. The only difference I see in page layouts where these controls work and don’t work is AutoEventWireup="true". I tried adding this attribute to the page layout which is not working but SharePoint started to give error that this attribute is not allowed. Now no matter what I do, add or remove this attribute from my layout I keep getting error.

Another difference I noticed is that this layout was previously updated, other layouts were most probably never updated after website was migrated from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010. The only way I can make these pages work is by removing these controls from the page,

please help me find a solution to this situation. I have already read a bunch of articles about "AutoEventWireup" I am not sure if this is the problem, nothing seems to provide a solution in my current situation.

Comment: What does it mean "this layout was previously updated"? Are you sure the layouts are being read from the physical files and that they are not "unghosted"? (i.e. read from the database). That would make a difference.

Comment: This I am sure that whatever layout version I upload to the SharePoint library it is being used, because when I remove controls it starts working and when I add controls it starts to give error.